# How do I to create a layout with jumbotron and navbar?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to create a layout using `jumbotron` and `navbar` but I cannot do it. I want that the `jumbotron` is located on top and the `navbar` is under of it. After I created I don't know why it has space on top and between the `navbar`.

How do I fix this ?

trying

```
<!-- Header.cshtml to use as a Partial to include on main layout -->

<header class="jumbotron bg-red">
    <h1>My first layout</h1>
    <h3>Trying to create a layout using jumbotron and navbar</h3>
</header><!--jumbotron-->

<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")" class="navbar-brand"><img src="~/Imagens/logo.png" width="32" height="32" title="Red Cherry" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
            </ul>
            @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!--nav bar-->
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you having this issue, have you changed anything in the bootstrap css?

For a quick fix you can do some css, add a class 'remove-space' to the **header** tag.

```
<header class="jumbotron bg-red remove-space">
```

Then apply this css to it.

```
.remove-space{
    margin: -50px 0 0 0;
 }
```